# ¿Cómo hacer campos obligatorios en Python?

Tags: python

Buen día; estoy haciendo un ejercicio con Python con la finalidad de una conexión a una base de datos que utiliza CRUD.

Pero, al momento de crear, veo errores; por ejemplo, que tiene cinco campos si solo digita nombre, y el resto no. Quedan en blanco en la BD, la pregunta es ¿Cómo colocar todos los campos obligatorios?

Estoy utilizando [tkinter](/questions/tagged/tkinter). Hice funciones de: crear, leer, actualizar y eliminar. En crear y actualizar, tengo consultas que usan parámetros.

```py
datos = miNombre.get() , miPass.get() , miApellido.get() , miDireccion.get() , textoComentario.get("1.0", END)
```

Comment: Seguramente debes validar que los datos tengan valores antes de tratar escribirlos en la base de datos. Puedes poner los campos de la tabla en la base de datos como `NOT NULL` y la base de datos no te permitirá almacenarlos si falta información, arrojara un error al tratar de almacenarlos

Answer (score 1):

Buen día,

No existe el atributo "requerido" u "obligatorio" en Tkinter, tendrías que escribir una función que revise si el campo de entrada está vacío o no. Luego usar esta función dentro del botón que envía la información a tu base de datos.

Ejemplo con un solo campo de entrada:

```
import tkinter as tk

def enviar_info():
    if campo_obligatorio.get():
        # El usuario ingresó datos en el campo obligatorio
        print("Campo de entrada con información")
        root.destroy()
    else:
        # El campo de entrada está vacío
        print("El campo de entrada está vacío")
        campo_obligatorio.focus_set()

root = tk.Tk()

campo_obligatorio = tk.Entry(root)

tk.Label(root, text="Data *").grid(row=0, column=0)
campo_obligatorio.grid(row=0, column=1)
tk.Button(root, text='Next', command=enviar_info).grid(row=1, columnspan=2)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Que  bien  voy a revisar codificando ,,y lo publico gracias

Comment: @innovaTecn, si la respuesta te fue útil no olvides aceptarla, de esa forma ayudas a otros usuarios a encontrar la solución a preguntas similares y al mismo tiempo ayudas a la comunidad a mantener abiertas únicamente las preguntas que no han sido resueltas